# Yii Framework: Alias "application.extensions.langhandler.ElangHandler" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file

Tags: permissions, yii, alias

I have a site developed and is working fine on development machine (Mac OS X 10.7). However when I port it over to a Linux server I ran into error:

```
Alias "application.extensions.langhandler.ElangHandler" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file
```

It supposedly is a permission problem according the below article:
http://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/detail?id=3039

However, I checked and the protected/extensions folder and down all have 755 permission. I even tried t make them all 777 just to see if I can get it working at all, but it didn't work either.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hint: you can also use 'ext' instead of 'application.extensions'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check that the spelling in filenames and class name is correct. OSX is case insensitive, while Linux is not.

Comment: Thank you, that was it! ELangHandler