# PHP: Installing minScript extension to Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

I have been debugging this for quite some time and am unable to find any solution - so this is my last hope.

I am trying to install/configure an extension for Yii called minScript by following this  [installation](https://bitbucket.org/limi7less/minscript/wiki/Installation) guide.

I place the extracted extension in my extensions folder, and change the config/main.php to the following:

```
return array(
'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
'name'=>'Demo app',

'controllerMap'=>array(
    'min'=>array(
        'class'=>'ext.minScript.controllers.ExtMinScriptController',
    ),
),

...

// application components
'components'=>array(
    'clientScript'=>array(
        'class'=>'ext.minScript.components.ExtMinScript',
        'minScriptDebug'=>true,
    ),

 ...
```

Although when I try to run it, I get an error message:

> CException
>
> Alias "ext.minScript.components.ExtMinScript" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.

The file exists in the defined folder and is readable, yet the error message always appears.

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your installation is on Linux, [be careful with spelling in file and directory names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188247/yii-framework-alias-application-extensions-langhandler-elanghandler-is-invali). I wasted a lot of time trying to solve the same problem with views and other components or extensions,

If not, try removing:

```
'minScriptDebug'=>true,
```

From your 'components' block.

Also assets and protected/runtime should be writtable (recursively).

Your file structure should look like:

```
protected/extensions/minScript/
                              components/
                                        ExtMinScript.php
                              controllers/
                                        ExtMinScriptController.php
                              vendors/...
                                        minify/...
```

And finally maybe you have a trouble with [urls](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager), routing rules or with your .htaccess / web server setup. In first case, in config/main.php I use all the urls with format domain.com/site/parm1/parm2 and adding this before routing rules solved the trouble:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
   'urlFormat'=>'path',
```

EDIT: I forgot this:

'controllerMap' section should be after 'components' in config/main.php,

Good luck!

Comment: It seems to be working now. I moved the controllerMap and enabled the urlManager and that seemed to do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try insert before return (you need to declare alias `ext` - set it on extension directory):

> ```
> Yii::setPathOfAlias('ext',
>    dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'extension';
> ```

Comment: According to http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.namespace#root-alias you don't need to define the ext namespace as it's predefined by Yii. I did try to add it though, but it still produces the same error.

Comment: check, please, result of Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext.minScript.components')